# MATLAB equivalent of Python's assignment of multiple values

Tags: python, matlab

I want to assign multiple values of `X`  like below:

```
>> X = [1:5]
>> [a,b,c,d,e] = X'
Error using  ' 
Too many output arguments.
```

In Python, `[a,b,c,d,e] = X.T` will work. I checked `deal()` and there are work arounds using `deal()` and `cell`. Is there an elegant way to condense the code this way?

Comment: I don't think there's an elegant way like in Python. You need `[a,b,c,d,e] = deal(1,2,3,4,5)` or `X = {1,2,3,4,5}; [a,b,c,d,e] = X{:};`

Comment: You could try `a,b,c,d,e = range(X)`

Comment: need something along the lines of [a,b,c,d,e] = deal(X{:})